# How to make text in cell visible

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Each field contains text, but how can I display it?

See C9 — it contains text, like all other cells:

[image]

How can I make it visible?

Answer (score 0):

you can alter the row height to automatic in its properties.

See [libreoffice help](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Optimal_Height)